# Making parts of my website more mobile and different screen resolution size friendly

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

My issues are as follows, I took a part of a resume website I am working on, most things resize well for mobile. Using bootstrap that would be expected. I know that I am not the best at this and am looking for a way to optimize the following sections of code to be more mobile and different screen size friendly.

Everything seems to resize well for mobile except the date on the far right side as well as the location on the far right side. It seems to move around and jump to different lines depending on the screen size.

Any tips for those or solutions? Possibly better ways for other parts of my code?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j49725p3/

```css
html{
        background-color: White;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    .lipad:before{ content:"• "; font-size:12pt; }
    
    #name {
        font-size: 42px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 200;
        color: #373737;
    }
    
    .posi {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: red;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .bold {
        font-size: 42px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #373737;
    }
    
    .continf {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none!important;
        color: #373737;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .qut {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #373737;
    }
    
    .mains {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: red;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .mains:after {
        content:"";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 0.3em;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: -100%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .blk {
        color: #373737;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    .subhead {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #373737;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .subtext {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #686868;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    
    .loca {
        padding-left: 78%;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: red;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .date {
        padding-left: 63.4%;
        padding-top: 0;
        color: #686868;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <!-- Required meta tags -->
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
          <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
          <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
          <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
          <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/26f7ef2ebf.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).on('load',function(){
              $('.preloader').addClass('complete')
            })
          </script>
          <script>
    var isVisible = false;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
         var shouldBeVisible = $(window).scrollTop()>200;
         if (shouldBeVisible && !isVisible) {
              isVisible = true;
              $('.gotop').show();
         } else if (isVisible && !shouldBeVisible) {
              isVisible = false;
              $('.gotop').hide();
        }
    });
            </script>
          <title>Joseph Kuzera | Resume</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <section class="my-5">
              <!-- Section heading -->
      <p class="text-center h1-responsive my-5 qut">“With hard work and dedication, anything is possible.”
      </p>
      <!-- Section description -->
      <h2 class="lead grey-text w-50 mx-auto mains">Edu<span class="blk">cation</span></h2>
      <div class="container b-0 p-0 w-50"><p class="subhead">College Of Dupage <span class="loca">Glen Ellyn, IL</span></p>
       <p class="subtext">A.A.S. IN COMPUTER INFORMATION SYSTEMS <span class="date">August 2015-August 2018</span></p>
       <ul class="entry-content extra">
          <li class="lipad">Was always in good standing maintaining a GPA of 3.5 or above.</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries and define your styling for each component for different screen sizes. see example below:

> column class has width 25%

But when screen width is less than 600px then

> column class has width 100%

Read more from https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

```
/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
 .column {
       float: left;
       width: 25%;
 }

/* On screens that are 992px wide or less, go from four columns to two columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```